# Write labels on edges with a complex tree implementation

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I'm breaking my mind to find an answer with documentation but I have some difficulties,

I asked a question to make a complex tree-like the following and now I'm working on the base implementation to make some customization, in particular, I want to add some label on the red and green arrow because I want indicate the value that is returning the function on the tree, but I'm no able to customize the solution with this feature.

[image]

In addition, I want to add some label on the right with the name of the array, like the following picture

[image]

This is my actual implementation

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree = {
        % nodes
            circle, draw, fill=gray!30,
            minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
        /tikz/every label/.style = {font=\tiny},
        /tikz/FIT/.style = {draw, very thick, rounded corners, fill=gray!30,
                            inner sep=4pt, inner ysep=8pt, yshift=-4pt,
                            fit=#1},
        % tree
        /tikz/every edge/.style={draw, -Straight Barb, 
                                 -Straight Barb, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt,
                                 bend angle = 15},% style for bended arrows
            edge=semithick,
            l sep=4mm,
            s sep=12mm,
            where level=3{l sep=11mm}{},% at level 3 increase l sep
            where level=4{no edge, very thick, fill=white}{},
            where level=5{no edge, very thick, fill=white}{},
                    }% level 4 is the lowest
        [1, label=below:{1:[0,7]},  name=t0
            [1, label=below:{2:[0,3]},  name=t11
                [2, label=below:{[0,1]},  name=t21
                    [2, thick, label=below:{[0,0]}
                        [2, label=below:0, name=n0
                            [0, label=below:0] 
                        ]
                    ]
                    [4, label=below:{9:[1,1]}, name=t31
                        [4, label=below:1
                            [0, label=below:1] 
                        ] 
                    ]
                ]
                % to paint the node I can use draw=none,fill=gray, 
                [1, label=below:{5:[2,3]}
                    [3, label=below:{10:[2,2]}
                        [3,  label=below:2
                            [0, label=below:2] 
                        ]
                    ]
                    [1, label=below:{11:[4, 4]}
                        [1, label=below:3
                            [0, label=below:3] 
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [5, very thick,edge=thick, label=below:{3:[4,7]}, name=t62
                [6, thick,edge=thick, name=t61
                    [6, thick,edge=thick,
                        [6, label=below:4
                            [0, label=below:4] 
                        ]
                    ]
                    [7, very thick,edge=thick, name=t6
                        [7, label=below:5, name=n6
                            [0, label=below:5] 
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                [8, very thick,edge=thick, name=t81
                    [8, very thick,edge=thick, 
                        [8, label=below:6, name=n7
                            [0, label=below:6] 
                        ]
                    ]
                    [10, very thick,edge=thick, name=t7
                        [10, label=below:7, name=n8
                            [0, label=below:7] 
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
             ]
        ]
        \scoped[on background layer]
        \node[FIT=(n7) (n8)] {};
        \draw[color=red]
            (t0) edge [bend right] (t62) 
            (t62) edge [bend right] (t81)
            (t81) edge [bend right] (t7);
        \draw[color=green]
            (t7) edge [bend right] (t81) 
            (t81) edge [bend right] (t62)
            (t62) edge [bend right] (t0);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: amend the following line -- `(t0) edge [bend right]node[below, ]{\scriptsize below} (t62) ` -- have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labeling of bended arrows can be simple done by using `quotes` library (see MWE below), for example:

```
    \draw[color=red]
        (t0)  edge [bend right, "a"] (t62)
        (t62) edge [bend right, "b"] (t81)
        (t81) edge [bend right, "c"] (t7);
```

Edge quotes style  you can define as:

```
/tikz/every edge quotes/.style={auto=right,
                                font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt},% style for bended arrows quotes
```

If you like to have different style, just change above definition accordingly.

Unfortunately it is not clear what you mean with "I want to add some label on the right with the name of the array, like the following picture" Please clarify this. Where is this array, what is in this aray? In generally you can add them in some new node, for example:

```
\node[right=1em] at (<coordinate>)
    {Lazy[]=\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
             \hline
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 4 \\
             \hline
             \end{tabular}};
```

**Edit:**

Temporary I add label "laty[ ] = " left of bottom levels (4 an 5) of diagram.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, draw, fill=gray!30,
    minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
/tikz/every label/.style = {font=\tiny},
/tikz/FIT/.style = {draw, very thick, rounded corners, fill=gray!30,
                    inner sep=3pt, inner ysep=7pt, yshift=-3.5pt,
                    fit=#1},
% tree
/tikz/every edge/.style={draw, -Straight Barb,
                         shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt,
                         bend right = 15},% style for bended arrows
/tikz/every edge quotes/.style={auto=right,
                                font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt},% style for bended arrows quotes
    edge=semithick,
    l sep=4mm,
    s sep=12mm,
    where level=3{l sep=11mm}{},% at level 3 increase l sep
    where level=4{no edge, very thick, fill=white}{},
    where level=5{no edge, very thick, fill=white}{},
            }% level 4 is the lowest
%%%% tree body
    [1, label=below:{1:[0,7]},  name=t0
        [1, label=below:{2:[0,3]},  name=t11
            [2, label=below:{[0,1]},  name=t21
                [2, thick, label=below:{[0,0]}
                    [0, label=below:0, name=n40
                        [0, label=below:0, name=n50]
                    ]
                ]
                [4, label=below:{9:[1,1]}, name=t31
                    [4, label=below:1
                        [0, label=below:1]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            % to paint the node I can use draw=none,fill=gray,
            [1, label=below:{5:[2,3]}
                [3, label=below:{10:[2,2]}
                    [3,  label=below:2
                        [0, label=below:2]
                    ]
                ]
                [1, label=below:{11:[4, 4]}
                    [1, label=below:3
                        [0, label=below:3]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [5, very thick,edge=thick, label=below:{3:[4,7]}, name=t62
            [6, thick,edge=thick, name=t61
                [6, thick,edge=thick,
                    [6, label=below:4
                        [0, label=below:4]
                    ]
                ]
                [7, very thick,edge=thick, name=t6
                    [7, label=below:5, name=n6
                        [0, label=below:5]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [8, very thick,edge=thick, name=t81
                [8, very thick,edge=thick,
                    [8, label=below:6, name=n7
                        [0, label=below:6]
                    ]
                ]
                [10, very thick,edge=thick, name=t7
                    [10, label=below:7, name=n8
                        [0, label=below:7]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
         ]
    ]
    \node[left=4 mm of $(n40)!0.5!(n50)$] {Lazy[ ] = }; % <---   
    \scoped[on background layer]
    \node[FIT=(n7) (n8)] {};
    \draw[color=red]
        (t0)  edge ["a"] (t62)
        (t62) edge ["b"] (t81)
        (t81) edge ["c"] (t7);
    \draw[color=green]
        (t7)  edge ["1"] (t81)
        (t81) edge ["2"] (t62)
        (t62) edge ["3"] (t0);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you would like this (code is no present yet):

[image]

Comment: You have right, sorry about that, to answer your question, so "Please clarify this. Where is this array, what is in this array?". The nodes without edges to the bottom (level 4 and level 5) in my description are array and I want add a label to the left position of the first node of the level 4 and 5

Comment: @vincenzopalazzon, does this mean, that you like to have only "lazy[ ]" before bottom nodes or this nodes had to be presented as part of table? In the first I will add yust name before them.

Comment: yes, your intuition was correct, thanks so much :-D

Answer (score 3):

```
        (t0) edge [bend right]node[below, ]{\scriptsize below} (t62)
```

[image]

or

```
        (t0) edge [bend right]node[fill=white, sloped ]{\scriptsize below} (t62)
```

[image]

or

```
(t0) edge [bend right]node[draw=none, fill=white,  sloped, pos=0.7 ]{\tiny below} (t62)
```

[image]